# Running out of quotation marks. (Django statics with document.write)

Tags: javascript, html, django

This element:

```
<img id="img" src="{% static 'pd.jpg' %}" />
```

should go here:

```
popup.document.write("<img src={% static 'pd.jpg' %} />")
```

So think i need a third kind of quotation marks, or ?

```
popup.document.write(String(<img src="{% static 'pd.jpg' %}" />))
```

at least is not working.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`? Best approach would be to remove that, and use more modern and understandable methods of DOM manipulation instead, which'll save you on one of the delimiters

Comment: the image should be printable via popup.

Answer (score 0):

> So think I need a third kind of quotation marks, or ?

**No**: the template tags are resolved when the template is rendered. This is done by the server. JavaScript on the other hand will run by the browser, and *after* the template is rendered. You thus can make use of:

```
popup.document.write('<img src="{% static 'pd.jpg' %}" />')
```

The single quotation marks of the `{% static 'pd.jpg' %}` will thus *not* appear in the source of the page (which you can inspect in the browser).

Comment: Thanks, but your solution gives me a red underline in vscode.

Comment: @Strella: yes, that is because Visual Studio does not understand how these string literals interact, and interprets it as a single language, not a language that will produce content for another language. Did you try to run this with the server? Visual Studio assumes that you are writing simple JavaScript: it doesn't take into account that the parts between `{%` and `%}` are actually never there when the Django render engine has rendered the content.

Comment: Yes, the route in browser looks like ... %20/%20... everthing seems right expect this %20/%20

Comment: @Strella: that's likely due to spaces in the `STATIC_URL` setting.

Comment: The tag in the html part gets resolved without these %20 and points to the image.

Comment: @Strella: sure, because the `%20` is a result of the `{% static ... %}` template tag, that will prepend it with the `STATIC_URL`, and then percentage encode the string. If the `STATIC_URL` thus contains spaces, these will be percentage encoded...

Comment: yes. i use render(request, 'indes.html') and in the index all paths are /static/app/item.extension. Thanks, i'll look for a workaround, or a different approach.